# Factor to Datetime conversion in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have a dataframe that has a factor column containing DateTime data as the following:

```
Date.Time
2010-05-06T09:30:00.000000000-04
2010-05-06T09:31:00.000000000-04
```

I want to convert this column into DateTime column. I searched and tried some functions but it gives me 'NA' results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't pinpoint what the error is if you don't provide the code you've tried, but here's a possible way of dealing with dates:

```
new_date <- as.POSIXct(as.character(factor_date), format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000000000-04")
```

Here, the `as.character` will convert the factor to character first and then `format` parameter takes care of the conversion

Comment: Thanks...This worked. I was not passing the right format.

Comment: Awesome, please take care of the order of the date parameters though - whether you have `%m` first or `%d`